# Trying to setup Ubuntu server 20.04 as a file and music server

Tags: samba

Ive tried to install samba with the following commands but I get errors.

These commands are :

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
add user Tim
passwd gizmo
```

But I get the errors:

```
Unable to locate package python-glade2
Unable to locate package  system-config-samba
adduesr: please enter a username matching the regular expression configured via the NAME_REGEXT_[SYSTEM] configuration variable. Use the'--force-badname' option to relax this check or reconfigure   NAME_REGEX.
```

Regards, T Vieweg

Comment: Perhaps you are following old instructions. Both `python-glade2` and `system-config-samba` were removed from Ubuntu after 18.04. They are indeed not available in 20.04.

Comment: Just install `samba`, it will handle all the needed dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the command  for installing samba?